# How to change a component's property of another frame with a button click from another form?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a main form (`MainForm`) where in there is a tabbed pane with 4 tabs; the 2nd tab contains text-fields.

And on another form (`PanelForm`), there are text-fields and a button, which when clicked should send the data entered on this form's text-field to the main form's second tab's (`tab2`) text-field, and set the selected tab to the 2nd tab.

Below is my current code, but nothing is happening.

---

PanelForm:

```
private void edit_profile_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();
    mf.jTabbedPane8.setSelectedIndex(2);
    mf.get_record(last_name_tf.getText());
}
```

MainForm:

```
public void get_record(String ln){
    ln_update_search_tf.setText(ln);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more code? So a more complete overview is possible?